# Limit Refactoring Scope in Webstorm

Tags: refactoring, webstorm

Is there a way to configure Webstorm so that when it refactors, it ignores specific areas of my project.  Specifically, I would like to be able to ignore folders containing 3rd party dependencies and built assets, such as node_modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to tell IntelliJ IDEA not to look at files during a search/replace or during refactorings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682451/is-there-any-way-to-tell-intellij-idea-not-to-look-at-files-during-a-search-repl) -- although the answers here are more helpful than in the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a JavaScript library of these folders as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#d41181e812). They will be excluded from renaming and other refactorings scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can also mark directories as completely ignored - they will then not show up in Webstorm's project view, will not be included in searches, won't be scanned when refactoring, etc. This is typically useful for directories containing built assets.

Right click on the folder in the project view, and choose "Mark Directory As", then select "Ignored".