# WebStorm limit refactor scope to current file only

Tags: intellij-idea, scope, refactoring, webstorm

EDIT: Here's the link to the issue I created  [ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21956 ]

Is it possible to limit the refactoring scope of WebStorm to the file in which you've issued the refactor (by default)?

In this case I've got a file I'm editing and I want to refactor (rename) one variable. WebStorm then issues a search through all the files in the entire project. I've searched for this online and I can only find scope limitations for specific folders. I hope I'm not expected to create scope for each file.

**P.S.** I found this related question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197566/pycharm-limit-refactor-renaming-to-current-file). Though I'm unable to comment on it as I don't have 50 rep yet (for shame). Chances are that if it's not in PyCharm it's not in WebStorm (they share code) so this is more of a double check. If it turns out that it is really not present I'll add a link to a feature request I'll be posting to WebStorm issues.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Have you created the feature request? If so, please post the link. A possible workaround is to use the Find and Replace feature instead: place the caret on the word, hit Ctrl + W and then Ctrl + R.

Comment: @iled I kind of forgot about this question haha. I just created a ticket for this [ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21956 ]. I believe I saw a similar issue for IDEA (which has the same topic). Though it's been filed in 2014 :/.

Comment: Thanks for creating the ticket. I already have voted for it :)

Comment: @iled Great! I see they've assigned someone to the issue. How long it's going to take before they solve it is anyone's guess though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of WebStorm 2016.1.3 it doesn't seem to be possible to change the **default** behaviour of the `Rename Refactoring`. The only options available are for renaming within a [*limited* scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687689/3079302), in which case you can enable or disable the in-place mode ([see docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/rename-refactorings.html)).

Here are two possible workflows. I'll give instructions using PC keyboard shortcuts, but you can achieve the same through the context menus.

---

### Find and Replace

1. Move the caret to the symbol you wish to rename
2. Select the word with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
3. Open Replace dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
4. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and type the new name
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to replace current occurrence or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to replace all occurrences

---

### Rename Refactoring tool

1. Open Rename Refactoring tool with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
2. Type new name
3. Adjust the filters for `Search in comments and strings` and for `Search for text occurrences` (on by default)
4. Preview the refactoring (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
5. The `Find Refactoring Preview` pane will show up (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to focus), listing all the occurrences found
6. In this list, you can select in which files the refactoring will take place; for instance, you can exclude all files by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> in the parent group, and then pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> only in the target file

In this (*stupid*) example I am renaming `require` to `require2`. Several occurrences are found. I excluded all of them by excluding the main group, then just included one file. I could have excluded the remaining groups as well, or selected all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Delete</kbd> to exclude.

[image: refactor rename example]

---

### See also

- [Limit Refactoring Scope in Webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404829/limit-refactoring-scope-in-webstorm)
- [Is there any way to tell IntelliJ IDEA not to look at files during a search/replace or during refactorings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682451/is-there-any-way-to-tell-intellij-idea-not-to-look-at-files-during-a-search-repl)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it provides a nice work-around until this is fixed. I've edited my original question with a link to the feature request.

Comment: I stumbled across this looking for the same thing with PHPStorm. I also figured out how to exclude things with the refactor preview. My problem is that even though i actually exclude files, it's still refactoring them. I don't know if it's a bug or not. Just thought i'd leave this not here in case someone else stumbled across this as well.

Comment: @CasperWilkes Thank you for your comment. At the time I posted this, I confirmed that it did not refactor unselected files. If you confirmed that behavior in PHPStorm, I'd recommend you to set up a reproducible example and fill up a bug report with Jetbrains.