# Refactoring inside scope in JetBrains IDE

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to refactor a variable inside a function, but only inside that function. Is this possible in the JetBrains IDE's?

Example:

```
var global = 0;

function func1 (val) {
    if (val === global) {
        doSomething();
    } else if (val * 2 === global) {
        doSomethingElse();
    } else {
        doSomethingElseEntirely();
    }
}

function func2 (val) {
    if (val === global) {
        doSomething();
    } else if (val * 2 === global) {
        doSomethingElse();
    } else {
        doSomethingElseEntirely();
    }
}
```

If I try to change the variable `global` inside `func1` via refactor, it will be changed in all of globals scope, so in `func2` as well. I would like to prevent this. Is this possible?

Comment: You are trying to **refactor** global variable  .. so no -- your scenario is not possible. Your options: multi-caret editing or simple find/replace in selection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler workaround.

[image: webstorm refactoring]

1. Add a dummy `var global` within `func1`.
2. Use the Refactor > Rename tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>), while selecting any occurrence of `global` in `func1`.
3. Remove the line (place the caret in the line and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>) added in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know "current file" is the smallest scope possible.

Workaround:

To achive what you want with the least effort, I suggest to use the normal search.

1. Search "global" (Strg + F)
2. place the cursor before or above the first occurence of "global" in your function (to get right starting point and remove focus from the search field)
3. click "Add Selection for Next Occurence" (or Alt+J) as often as needed
4. rename all occurences at once by typing in the new name

some manual work needed here, but I think its the fastest way for big functions.