# PyCharm how to set default refactor rename scope

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm provides option to rename text in different scopes via `Shift + F6`. By default the rename scope is set to `Project Files`. Every time I need to rename something I have to either select current file in scope option or select exclude in refactoring prompt. Is there an option to set rename scope to `Current File` by default in the pop up specific to a project or for whole IDE?

I found this similar question from 2016, [WebStorm limit refactor scope to current file only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616672/webstorm-limit-refactor-scope-to-current-file-only).

**EDIT:**
`Ctrl + R` seems to get the job done for my current requirement of renaming within current file by using replace all. I would still prefer to know if default option setting is available.

[image]

Comment: 1) A ticket for PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41064 -- no activity there.

Comment: 2) [A comment here (IntelliJ IDEA / Platform-wide ticket)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228855#focus=Comments-27-3885517.0-0) tells that the current behaviour (not remembering the scope from the previous invocation) is intended. It also has [duplicate ticket (quite recent one)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259871) .. so for me it looks like devs do not currently plan to change anything here. **P.S.** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21681 -- ticket for  introduction of the `Current File` scope for Rename refactoring dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the ticket links. It seems there isn't much interest in this feature. So far `Ctrl + R` is quick workaround instead of selecting from dropdown.

Comment: Maybe it's faster .. but not safer. E.g. in case if you have the same variable used in few different methods/classes etc -- sorry, I'm more of a PHP person using "1 class per file; no global scope, mainly classes; not re-using variable for diff purposes in the same scope" approach where this is not an issue for me (the default scope is already good in almost all cases). Anyway: I suggest you ping that #1 ticket -- see if devs have anyting to say there (do not mention the #2)